# TWILIO FB messenger usage acceptance

Tags: twilio, facebook-messenger

I want to use Twilio to send messages thru SMS and Facebook Messenger.
What kind of messages could I send ? is there any usage acceptance policy ?
And how about send FB Messages to a new user ? will be asked any kind of opt-in ?
Is there any integration document ?

thanks a lot

Comment: This would be better to ask Twilio's support team and usage docs, as it isn't exactly a programming question

Comment: Read https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/04/twilio-announces-integration-with-facebook-messenger-and-viber.html blog and request access to get more details .As @jbutler483 mentioned, not a programming question .